# How to find distance of a polyline in google maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Can you tell me how to get a distance of a polyline between to points in google maps in android?

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(75.5, -1.1), new LatLng(60.7, -84.0), 80.7, -32.0))
 .width(5)
 .color(Color.BLUE));
```

In above code i have drawn a path using polyline. So i want to know how to i calculate ot get the distance of this polyline. I know there are some methods such as "distanceTo". THose methods gives you the distance between to points. But in my case i have few points as you can see in the above example, to draw a single polyline.

Comment: you want to find distance between points of polylines right?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Polyline polylin;
ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint;
PolylineOptions rectLine;
Document doc;
GMapV2Direction md;
```

and

```
public class showRoad extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Document>{

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {
        md = new GMapV2Direction();
        doc = md.getDocument(lastLocation, univ_position,
                GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

        directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

        rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                Color.BLUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        polylin = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
    }
}
```

and call it :

```
new showRoad().execute();
```

and finally add this class :

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV2Direction() {
}

public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
    Log.d("url", url);
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText(Document doc) {
    try {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "0";
    }
}

public int getDurationValue(Document doc) {
    try {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}

public String getDistanceText(Document doc) {
    /*
     * while (en.hasMoreElements()) { type type = (type) en.nextElement();
     *
     * }
     */

    try {
        NodeList nl1;
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");

        Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = null;
        nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.d("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
    }

    /*
     * NodeList nl1; if(doc.getElementsByTagName("distance")!=null){ nl1=
     * doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
     *
     * Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1); NodeList nl2 = null; if
     * (node1.getChildNodes() != null) { nl2 = node1.getChildNodes(); Node
     * node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value")); Log.d("DistanceText",
     * node2.getTextContent()); return node2.getTextContent(); } else return
     * "-1";} else return "-1";
     */
}

public int getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
    try {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = null;
        node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
    /*
     * NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance"); Node node1 =
     * null; if (nl1.getLength() > 0) node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
     * if (node1 != null) { NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes(); Node node2
     * = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value")); Log.i("DistanceValue",
     * node2.getTextContent()); return
     * Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent()); } else return 0;
     */
}

public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {
    try {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
    }

}

public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {
    try {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
    }
}
public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {
    try {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
    }

}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2
                    .item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr
                        .get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my one project... i am not sure this can help you or not but for finding distance from your polyline you can use PolyUtil class which contains one method distanceToLine .

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

add this library in your build.gradle. For more you can use Google map utility class.This library is provide by google you can find here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/

You can find some of the PolyUtil method description here...

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-

Hope this will help you..if any issue please inform me..i can help you on this.